# aTop like tool for OSX

Tags: macos, mac, cpu, process

I'm trying to debug some issues with my Mac. This machine is used as continuous integration server. It stops responding from time to time. I think it could be some software issue, since the machine is working (so i.e. it's not a kernel panic) - that is when I go to the server room I see the login screen and I can move the mouse. Unfortunately I can't login neither directly nor by VNC or SSH.

There is a nice tool that helps in debugging this type of problem called [aTop](http://www.atoptool.nl/). It's like top but with history. Unfortunately it's Linux-only software.

Is there any tool that is similar to aTop for OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[glances](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances) is a good alternative to atop for Mac. It has almost all features of atop and has several extensions as well. Users can also easily build new extensions on top of it. You can disable/enable logging history.

Answer (score 3):

You may wanna try [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/). In the homepage it says it's "htop - an interactive process viewer for Linux", but it actually also works for OS X.

Comment: thank you for answer but unfortunately htop doesn't store history.

Comment: Terminal <= `brew install htop`

Comment: atop has swap in / swap out activities of the kernel, which are not accessible in any macOS installable tooling I've found so far..atop was great at showing in red over swapping activities..we do have monitor / memory pressure that accounts for swapping activities..but would love to see a more detailed per process swapping view like atop used to offer on linux..

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try sysdig for recording and digging into what is happening on a server: `brew install sysdig`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an error:
"live capture not supported on Darwin"